# Android help needed on adapter view to set the text size

Tags: android, listview, view, textview

I am developing an android media player. I am new to ANDROID. I am using the following code to show all the music from a query result. I want every song once, but it showing a single song more than once and ignoring many others, if I set the text size in the adapter view as in the following code. How can I set the text size in the adapter view and avoid this problem?

Thank u

```
public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public MusicAdapter(Context c) {
              mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
              return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
              return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
              return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              System.gc();
              TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
              tv.setTextSize(25);                     //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
              String id = null;
              if (convertView == null) {
                    music_column_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    musicCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    id = musicCursor.getString(music_column_index);
                    music_column_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                    musicCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    String artist = musicCursor.getString(music_column_index);
                    id += "Artist:" + artist;
                    tv.setText(id);
              } else
                    tv = (TextView) convertView;
              return tv;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using SimpleCursorAdapter like below. It is a built in adapter, which is really smart. [This link helped me a lot](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

And you should never set android:layout_height="wrap_content" of a listview. It causes the repeating occurrence of list items.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            // Use a template that displays a text view
            R.layout.list_item,
            // Give the cursor to the list adatper
            musicCursor,
            // Map the NAME column in the people database to...
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST },
            // The "text1" view defined in the XML template
            new int[] { R.id.music_title, R.id.music_artist });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you write the same code within try{} statement and within while? ))

I mean these lines:

```
path.add(musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
            title.add(musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
            artist.add(musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
            album.add(musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
            year.add(musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR)));
```

Comment: No that's not the problem. Anyway thanks for your reply. I found out the cause.

Comment: So my question changed. It caused because of changing the text size in the adapter view.